# Ruby on Rails bundle install Couldn't Reserve Space for Cygwin's heap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

When I run bundle install on my rails command prompt on windows 10 pc. I am getting the following error. It worked fine once but after formatting my computer and reinstalling the bundle install doesn't seem to be working very well. It is showing a make error , couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap etc.etc. etc.

> Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
>   C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for
>   cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe:
>   *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160602-6432-42ucd5.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>         0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487 AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize
>   0x1E0000, State 0x10000 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: ***
>   Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> make "DESTDIR="
>         0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487 AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize
>   0x1E0000, State 0x10000 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: ***
>   Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> make failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
>   Using minitest 5.9.0 Using thread_safe 0.3.5 Using builder 3.2.2 Using
>   erubis 2.7.0 Using mini_portile2 2.0.0 Using rack 1.6.4 Using
>   mime-types-data 3.2016.0221 Using arel 6.0.3 Installing
>   debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions
>   C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for
>   cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe:
>   *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160602-6432-1l864zd.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>         0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487 AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize
>   0x1E0000, State 0x10000 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: ***
>   Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> make "DESTDIR="
>         0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487 AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize
>   0x1E0000, State 0x10000 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: ***
>   Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> make failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
>   Installing byebug 9.0.4 with native extensions
>   C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for
>   cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe:
>   *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160602-6432-1y5p971.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>         0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487 AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize
>   0x1E0000, State 0x10000 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: ***
>   Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> make "DESTDIR="
>         0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487 AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize
>   0x1E0000, State 0x10000 C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe: ***
>   Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
>
> make failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/byebug-9.0.4 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/byebug-9.0.4/gem_make.out
>   Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0 Using execjs 2.7.0 Using thor 0.19.1
>   Using commonjs 0.2.7 Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2 Using multi_json
>   1.12.1 Using tilt 2.0.4 Using bundler 1.12.5 Using sass 3.4.22 Using sqlite3 1.3.11 An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and
>   Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install json
>
> -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: try running gem update --system before anything else

Comment: Reboot the maching. Cygwins uses persistent shared memory sections, which can on occasion become corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruben Barbosa's comment seems to be a valid solution. At least for me, and some other users in duplicate questions... So:

> Reboot the maching. Cygwins uses persistent shared memory sections,
>   which can on occasion become corrupted.